# how to add characters to the end of the value if it already exists?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Here when I click post button it inserts a random value on database.
If a value  already exists on database then show error. It works fine.

But I want to add 2/3 characters at the end of value if it already exists on database. If `$check == 1` then I want to add  some characters at the end of the value instead of showing alert. How to do this?

```
<?php 

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","post") or die("unable to connect to internet");

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $slug = $_POST['rand'];
    $get_slug = "select * from slug where post_slug='$slug' ";
    $run_slug = mysqli_query($con,$get_slug );
    $check = mysqli_num_rows($run_slug );

    // if $check==1   then i want to add 2  characters at the end  of $slug .  

    if($check == 1)
    {
        //  instead of showing alert i want to add 2 more characters at the end of that value and and insert it on database

        echo "<script> alert('something is wrong') </script> ";
        exit ();
    }
    else
    {
        $insert ="insert into slug (post_slug) values ('$slug') "; 

        $run = mysqli_query($con,$insert);

        if($run)
        {
            echo "<p style='float:right;'> Posted  successfully </p>";
        }
    }
}
?>

<form method="POST" >
<?php
    $result = "";

    $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    $chararray = str_split($chars);
    for($i = 0; $i < 7 ; $i++)
    {
$randitem = array_rand($chararray);
        $result .= "".$chararray[$randitem];
    }
    echo $result ;
?>

    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $result;?>" name="rand" />

    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-info"  type="submit" name="submit">POST</button>
    </span>
</form>
```

Comment: For the second time do you want to update the existing value of insert another after adding strings

Comment: for check all possibilities from database check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41438239/how-to-add-characters-to-the-end-of-the-value-if-it-already-exists#answer-41438377

Comment: yes i want update it if already exists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just few modification in your code to insert new value.

```
<?php 

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","post") or die("unable to connect to internet");

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $slug = $_POST['rand'];
    $get_slug = "select * from slug where post_slug='$slug' ";
    $run_slug = mysqli_query($con,$get_slug );
    $check = mysqli_num_rows($run_slug );

    if($check == 1)
    {
        $slug_new = $slug.'ab'; // Add 2 characters at the end
        $update ="UPDATE slug SET post_slug = '$slug_new' WHERE post_slug = '$slug'";
        $run = mysqli_query($con,$update);
    }
    else
    {
        $insert ="insert into slug (post_slug) values ('$slug') ";
        $run = mysqli_query($con,$insert);

        if($run)
        {
            echo "<p style='float:right;'> Posted  successfully </p>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: can't i add else condition  normally as usual ?

Comment: I removed it to make code more compact and eliminate unwanted conditions. Can help you if you can explain why you need else condition or what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

just run update query if `$check == 1`

```
if($check == 1){
$newSlug = $slug."xy";    
$update = "update slug set post_slug = '".$newSlug."' where post_slug = '".$slug."'";
        $run = mysqli_query($con,$update );
        echo "<script> alert('Updated Successfully') </script> ";
        exit ();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is helpful for you

```
<?php 

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","post"  ) or die

( "unable to connect to internet");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $tmp_slug = $_POST['rand'];
        $slug = $_POST['rand'];

        while(check_exiest($tmp_slug))
        {
            $tmp_rand = rand(11,99);
            $tmp_slug = $slug.$tmp_rand;
        }

        $insert ="insert into slug (post_slug) values ('$tmp_slug') "; 

        $run = mysqli_query($con,$insert);

        if($run) 
        {
            echo "<p style='float:right;'> Posted  successfully </p>";
        }
}

public function check_exiest($slug)
{
    $get_slug = "select * from slug where post_slug='$slug' ";
    $run_slug = mysqli_query($con,$get_slug );
    $check = mysqli_num_rows($run_slug );

    if($check >= 1)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: +1 for OOB/Function. Functions are amazing for duplicated processes. Saves on time, code is clean and easy to read and maintenance is simple. One location rather than combing and hoping you found all the duplicated code blocks.