# Check duplicate when inserting new record

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I am new to Sugar CRM and I have made an custom module.
Now when creating a record I want to check that same name record exist then throw validation.

How can I do this?

Comment: For check duplicate value in db check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41438239/how-to-add-characters-to-the-end-of-the-value-if-it-already-exists/41438377#41438377

Comment: What version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

i think you need something like

```
   $QUERY = "select * from your_table where name = '$yourVariable'";
   $result = $db->query($query);
   if($result->num_rows > 0){
   echo "user already exists !";
   }else{
   your code here.......
   }
```